# How to Combine These Two MySQL Statements

Tags: mysql, wordpress, buddypress

I am using these two statements to query BuddyPress for friendships, but I am wondering if their is a better way or a way to combine these two MySQL statements:

```
    //Statement for friendship initiator
    $SQL1 = "SELECT wp_users.display_name AS'name', 
                    wp_users.user_login AS 'fname', 
                    wp_users.user_nicename AS 'surname' 
            FROM wp_users 
            INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends 
                  ON wp_users.id = wp_bp_friends.friend_user_id 
            WHERE 1=1 
               AND wp_bp_friends.initiator_user_id = " . $user_id . " 
               AND wp_bp_friends.is_confirmed = 1";


    //Statement for friendship non-initiator
    $SQL2 = "SELECT wp_users.display_name AS 'name', 
                    wp_users.user_login AS 'fname', 
                    wp_users.user_nicename AS 'surname' 
             FROM wp_users 
             INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends 
                   ON wp_users.id = wp_bp_friends.initiator_user_id 
             WHERE 1=1 
                   AND wp_bp_friends.friend_user_id = " . $user_id . " 
                   AND wp_bp_friends.is_confirmed = 1";
```

The result should contain a list of friendships based on the $user_id no matter if they initiated the relationship or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "
  SELECT u.display_name  AS name,
         u.user_login    AS fname,
         u.user_nicename AS surname
  FROM   wp_users        AS u
    JOIN wp_bp_friends   AS f
      ON (u.id, $user_id) IN (
           (f.friend_user_id,    f.initiator_user_id),
           (f.initiator_user_id, f.friend_user_id)
         )
  WHERE  f.is_confirmed = 1
";
```

---

**EDIT**

Per [@Quassnoi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822107/how-to-combine-these-two-mysql-statements/10822183#comment14086928_10822183) below, as elegant as the above answer is, it won't use indexes for the lookups (due to a MySQL implementation flaw).  Instead, you could do:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT u.display_name  AS name,
         u.user_login    AS fname,
         u.user_nicename AS surname
  FROM   wp_users        AS u
    JOIN wp_bp_friends   AS f
      ON (f.friend_user_id    = u.id AND f.initiator_user_id = $user_id)
      OR (f.initiator_user_id = u.id AND f.friend_user_id    = $user_id)
  WHERE  f.is_confirmed = 1
";
```

Comment: @Quassnoi: Oh yes, we're back to yesterday's point: I'd already forgotten.  Ugh.  One could explode the `IN` into explicit `... OR ...` clauses to be more index friendly.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm, and upped my education points, too!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which result came from which query, then you can easily combine them with a `UNION`, like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
   wp_users.display_name AS 'name', 
   wp_users.user_login AS 'fname', 
   wp_users.user_nicename AS 'surname' 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends ON wp_users.id = wp_bp_friends.friend_user_id 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_bp_friends.initiator_user_id = " . $user_id . " 
AND wp_bp_friends.is_confirmed = 1
UNION
SELECT 
   wp_users.display_name AS 'name', 
   wp_users.user_login AS 'fname', 
   wp_users.user_nicename AS 'surname' 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends ON wp_users.id = wp_bp_friends.initiator_user_id 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_bp_friends.friend_user_id = " . $user_id . " 
AND wp_bp_friends.is_confirmed = 1";
```

If it does matter which query they came from, then you can add a static varchar column to each query that you can use later to figure out which query the row came from:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'FIRST', 
   wp_users.display_name AS 'name', 
   wp_users.user_login AS 'fname', 
   wp_users.user_nicename AS 'surname' 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends ON wp_users.id = wp_bp_friends.friend_user_id 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_bp_friends.initiator_user_id = " . $user_id . " 
AND wp_bp_friends.is_confirmed = 1
UNION
SELECT 'SECOND',
   wp_users.display_name AS 'name', 
   wp_users.user_login AS 'fname', 
   wp_users.user_nicename AS 'surname' 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_bp_friends ON wp_users.id = wp_bp_friends.initiator_user_id 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_bp_friends.friend_user_id = " . $user_id . " 
AND wp_bp_friends.is_confirmed = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  u.display_name, u.user_login, u.user_nicename
FROM    wp_bp_friends f
JOIN    wp_users u
ON      u.id =
        CASE @userId
        WHEN f.initiator_user_id THEN
                f.friend_user_id
        WHEN f.friend_user_id THEN
                f.initiator_user_id
        END
WHERE   (
        f.initiator_user_id = @userId
        OR
        f.friend_user_id = @userId
        )
        AND f.is_confirmed = 1
```

Create the indexes on `initiator_user_id` and `friend_user_id`.

This will use `index_merge` which (with `InnoDB`) is marginally more efficient than a `UNION` of two resultsets, due to more sequential access to `wp_bp_friends`.